# Passing an Action<interface> to to be executed against list of concrete implementations

Tags: c#, lambda, interface, delegates, func

So I have this

```
public interface ITask
{
    void PrintName(string props);
    void PrintState();
}

public class Epic: ITask
{
    public Epic() { }
    public void PrintName(string props)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello Epic: " + props);
    }
    public void PrintState(string props)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Epic Started");
    }
}


public class Story: ITask
{
    public Story() { }
    public void PrintName(string props)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello Story: " + props);
    }
    public void PrintState(string props)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Story Started");
    }
}

public class TaskProxy : ITask
{
    List<ITask> list;
    public TaskProxy (List<ITask> list) 
    { 
        this.list = list;
    }
    public void PrintName(string props)
    {            
      foreach(ITask tsk in list)
      {
        tsk.PrintName(props);
      }
    }
    public void PrintState()
    {            
      foreach(ITask tsk in list)
      {
        tsk.PrintState();
      }
    }
}
```

which I am executing as

```
class Program
{
    static List<ITask> list = new List<ITask>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        list.Add(new Story());
        list.Add(new Epic());

        ITask task = TaskProxy(list );
        task.PrintName("some props")
        task.PrintState()
    }
}
```

But I want this instead to be re-written as Action<> generic which will execute all similar methods in the context of a different Implementation. (something like method borrowing?)

```
public class TaskProxy : ITask
{
    List<ITask> list;
    public TaskProxy (List<ITask> list) 
    { 
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void PrintName(string props)
    {            
       Generic(ITask.PrintName(props)) // looking for something like this    
    }

    public void PrintState()
    {            
       Generic(ITask.PrintState())  // looking for something like this   
    }

    public void Generic(Action methodToExecute)
    {            
       foreach(ITask tsk in list)
       {
          tsk.methodToExecute();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really unclear to me what you're trying to do. What would you expect the `Func<>` to return? Are you actually looking for an `Action<ITask>`? (A func returns something; an action doesn't.) As a side-note, I'd strongly encourage you to follow normal naming conventions when writing sample code like this - it avoids distracting readers.

Comment: Even now that you've changed to Action (in the body - you still need to do the title) it's not clear what you're trying to do. You could accept an `Action<ITask>` and call `action(tsk);` on each item in the list... I'm not sure why you're expecting to be able to call `tsk.action()` though...

Comment: Sorry,  I have a IInterfaceProxyImplementation which executes each interface methods against all other implementations of IInterface in a loop.

trying to avoid loop in each interface implementation of IInterfaceProxyImplementation  by creating generic methods. 

Will try to be more clear nextime

Comment: No, please be more clear *this* time. I strongly suspect that if you don't edit your question to clarify it, you won't get an answer. (Certainly I don't have enough information to answer it.) Do you still *want* an answer to this question? For a start, it would be worth defining an interface with more than one method, if the point is to be able to execute multiple methods...

Comment: @JonSkeet Hopefully its more clear this time

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually thanks for the push, improving my question helped my get the answer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic variant could look like this:

```
public void Generic(Action<ITask> iTaskMethodToExecute)
{            
    foreach(ITask tsk in list)
    {
        iTaskMethodToExecute(tsk);
    }
}
```

Explanation: `Action<ITask>` stands for an action that takes an `ITask` as parameter. This allows you to access in a lambda expression all the methods that ITask provides.

You would call it then like this:

```
List<ITask> list = new List<ITask>();

list.Add(new Story());
list.Add(new Epic());

TaskProxy task = new TaskProxy(list );
task.Generic(x => x.PrintName("some props"));
task.Generic(x => x.PrintState());
```

On the first glance it might look a little confusing to insert a `ITask` as parameter into the action as in this line:

```
iTaskMethodToExecute(tsk);
```

But if you look at the lambda expression call:

```
task.Generic(x => x.PrintState());
             ^
             |
         input of type: ITask
```

it should make sense because only this way the compiler is able to infer the type and intelisense will suggest even the methods in autocomplete:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I need ! Thank you so much!
if you have any good tutorials on improving my generics , I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Dexters I am glad that I could help. concenrning tutorials unfortunately nothing comes to mind so fast.

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose reflection would be a viable approach. The solution could look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace CsharpPlayground
{

    public class Code
    {
        interface ITask
        {
            void printName();
        }
        class Story : ITask
        {
            public void printName()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Story");
            }
        }
        class Epic : ITask
        {
            public void printName()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Epic");
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tasks = new List<ITask>
            {
                new Story(),
                new Epic()
            };

            // Approach 1
            Console.WriteLine("Approach 1");
            foreach (var task in tasks)
            {
                task.printName();
            }

            // Approach 2
            Console.WriteLine("\nApproach 2");
            void GenericExecuted(MethodInfo method)
            {
                foreach (ITask tsk in tasks)
                {
                    method?.Invoke(tsk, new object[0]);
                }
            }
            var printMethod = typeof(ITask).GetMethod(nameof(ITask.printName));
            GenericExecuted(printMethod);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks the 2nd approach is what I was trying to do but trying to avoid reflection.